Can there be Bal Tosif with regards to the Ketores?
If an additional spice was mixed into the Ketores, is it considered Bal Tosif to offer it on the Mizbe'ach, or would it be just like if the blood of a sacrifice was mixed with the blood of Chulin, which is generally allowed to be offered (Mishnah Zevachim 8:6)?

If you left out all but one or two, would that be Bal Tigra?

חסר אחת מכל סממניה חייב מיתה

There are two ways of transgressing Bal Tosif as explained in this OU article: [1] adding a detail to a mitzvah and [2] adding a mitzvah to Taryag.
Mixing an additional spice into the Ketores seems to be adding a detail to a particular mitzvah, similar to having five compartments for the tefillin and will be forbidden because of  Bal Tosif.

Or it could be considered a random spice mix and not ketores at all.

@Chatzkel Kind of what I was thinking above.

That's only at home. Not if you use it as THE offering. Just like -1 would be allowed at home

@Mordechai if you use it as THE offering, wouldn’t there be an issue of chullin baazara or other issurim, not bal tosif. Bal tosif is if you did the mitzvah plus, here he doesn’t have ketores at all

So why death if you miss one spice? Chullin bazara doesn't get that

The answer can depend on when the additional spice is added.
